# MySQL transactions are not isolated according to integrity constraint violation exception

Tags: mysql, transactions

I have a key-value table called `migration_logs` with 2 columns key, being unique, and value both varchar(255).

```
CREATE TABLE `migration_logs` (
 `key` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `value` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 UNIQUE KEY `migration_logs_key_unique` (`key`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Then I have the following Laravel code:

```
class MigrationLog {
    ...
    public static function beginMigration($userId)
    {
        $shouldMigrate = false;
        $key = "luser:$userId/migration_pushed";
        \DB::beginTransaction();

        if (!self::query()->where('key', '=', $key)->first()) {
            self::create([
                'key'   => $key,
                'value' => Carbon::now(),
            ]);
            $shouldMigrate = true;
        }

        \DB::commit();

        return $shouldMigrate;
    }
}
```

**Note: You may consider I did not catch the exceptions appropriately, which is true. But my question is about the behaviour of MySQL, not about exception handling in the PHP code.**

You don't need to know laravel to help me. What beginMigration() does is that check if a key exists and if not, set some value for it, all inside a mysql transaction. The isolation level is MySql default.

When two process call beginMigration() with the same input, I expect one set the key and the other does nothing.

However, I find a situation when one process set the key and the other one tried to set it, hence a `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry` exception thrown.

I want to know how is it possible? What is wrong? And how to fix?

MySQL version: 5.6.27

Comment: Does it work if the 2 callers are distinct - separated by a few seconds?  It looks like the query could return false for any number of simultaneous actions, with the commit failing.  However I don't know `laravel`, and how it would cope with a failure/exception

Comment: The code have worked for normal scenarios, for 1000 times. What I wrote here is a snippet with minor omissions and simplifications.

Comment: I double checked now. The first call of beginMigration(10001) returns true and the second call returns false, which is what I expect when things happen sequentially.

Comment: I can't see how this should work. New rows will not exist for other sessions until you commit the transaction. Until them, any check you run will determine the key does not exist. Perhaps you're thinking on table locking rather than transactions :-?

Comment: So this seems to be a laravel issue,  how do you catch the exception from the commit (`SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry exception thrown.`) - when the second process fails the commit.  Then make sure that `shouldMigrate` is reset.

Comment: You are right, but MySQL should not throw `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry` either, if the two transactions are perfectly isolated. Am I right? @mksteve

Comment: What does self::create do?  Is it using the same DB handle?

Comment: self::create performs an insert query. I am sure all the code above is within the same DB connection.

Comment: Can it be a MySQL bug. Or I should not expect the default isolation level works?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like I should increase the isolation level before beginning the transaction by executing this query:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
```

With that, instead of integrity constraint violation exception, I receive this exception from MySQL:

```
SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
```

Having said that, a better solution to my problem would be relying on mysql error instead of using transaction:

```
public static function beginMigration($userId)
{
    $key = "luser:$userId/migration_pushed";
    try {
        self::create([
            'key'   => $key,
            'value' => Carbon::now(),
        ]);
        return true;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason you have to catch the MySQL error is that constraint enforcement is not done at commit time.  It is done early. As soon as the successful transaction commits the row, the unsuccessful transaction is granted the necessary locks and discovers that the insert is now impossible. Transactions aren't allowed to continue past statements that will result in a commit being impossible.  This behavior is arguably wrong, but it is how MySQL (or, more accurately, InnoDB) works.

Comment: Also note that deadlock detection is your friend.  The deadlock error is telling you that the two transactions are intermingling their row/index locks in such a way that one of them is not likely to succeed, and had the deadlock not been detected, they would have waited forever for each other, blocking on incompatible locks.  The transaction that has made the least progress in terms of rows locked when the deadlock is detected will be killed, and needs to be retried, at which point you will hit the integrity constraint error.

Answer (score 0):

### Update

The isolation of a transaction ensures that within a DB transaction then only committed data is seen.

```
   BEGIN
   INSERT INTO mytable (a,b,c ) VALUES ('x', 'y', 'z' );
   INSERT INTO mytable2 (d,e,f ) VALUES ('u', 'v', 'w' );
   COMMIT
```

Other users of the database will either see neither 'x','y', 'z' and 'u', 'v', 'w' or both.  Not half of the transaction.

When you query in a transaction, you are querying *committed* data.  So 2 processes inserting the same data, will both see the space is available.

When the DB system performs the conflicting commits, it ensures only the first transaction succeeds, and fails (by throwing an exception) all the others.

From the `php` and `laravel` documentation, it appears that the expected behavior of the `commit` is an exception.

The code shown would set `$shouldMigrate` to true, but when failing, would throw an exception.

If `$shouldMigrate` has a scope outside of the function, then this would cause a failure.  Also there probably is a `try` / `catch` block which is stopping the process to abort.  The handling of the catch may not propagate the error.

```
try {
    \DB::commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Exception',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    $shouldMigrate = false;
}
```

Would be the simplest fix I could think of.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but the exception happens before \DB::commit().

Comment: Shouldn't MySQL return a lock related error instead of integrity constraint violation?